# Paypal Not compatible with Device

Tags: objective-c, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Since two days I am getting weird errors/responses in PayPal while login
 “This app contains payment capabilities that aren’t compatible with your device”,I am getting this error while I am trying to login .Is anyone else also facing this issue (or has faced it in past)?

Comment: I am also getting this kind of issue...is Adaptive payment deprecated using MPL library?